# I am tring to add a year to a date if it is not before today.

Tags: sql, dateadd

I am tring to add a year to a date if it is not before today. So in the statement below I would like to display 4/20/2018

```
declare @StartDate datetime
set @StartDate='4/20/2015'
select case when dateadd(year,1,@StartDate)> GETDATE() then 
dateadd(year,1,@StartDate) else dATEADD(year,1,(datepart(year,GETDATE()))) end
```

Comment: ON the first part of your case you return a date 1 year + @start date = 4/20/2016.  on the else part you return an integer.  or it errors... why are you attempting to part out the year? and then add 1 year to it?  Since year isn't a valid date does this even compile? you can't mix data types on a column output!

Comment: I know that it error and trying to figure out how the else statement would display 4/20/2018 since the @StartDate +1 is less then the current date.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the else clause so it works out the difference between the start date and today's date +1 to alter make '4/20/2015' become '4/20/2018'

```
declare @StartDate date
set @StartDate='4/20/2015'
select 
case 
when dateadd(year,1,@StartDate)> GETDATE() then dateadd(year,1,@StartDate) 
else DATEADD(year,(datepart(year,GETDATE())+1-datepart(year,@StartDate)),@StartDate) 
end
```

Also if you are not using the `time` part of a `datetime` data type it's best practice to use `date` instead as it only requires 3 bytes of storage rather than 8 for `datetime`.
More on `date` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql
And a cheatsheet of sql data types here: https://sqlserverrider.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/pic116.png

Comment: Thats Works! Thank You

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @user3818712 happy to have helped! If this works can you make this as the answer please! :)